# Style the title bar with a monotouch application

Tags: xamarin.ios

I found a cool photoshop template for iOS and I have modified the style to suit what I need. So the easy part done I need to convert it to work with my monotouch application using a TabBarController.

[image]

Is it possible to either apply an image to the background or do something similar to css where I take a 1px wide image and repeat the style 100%?